# Why does this interface implementation in F# not compile?

Tags: generics, interface, f#, equality

I am trying to implement `IEquatable<T>` for a particular class in F#. However, when doing so in this particular, I get an unexpected error.

I have the following code:

```
type Foo private (name : string) = 

member this.Name = name

member this.Equals (other : Foo) = this.Name = other.Name

override this.Equals other =
    match other with | :? Foo as foo -> this.Equals foo | _ -> false

override this.GetHashCode () = this.Name.GetHashCode ()

interface IEquatable<Foo> with
    this.Equals other = this.Equals other
```

This does not compile. I get the following error: "Unexpected keyword 'with' in member definition'. Also, I get a "Possible incorrect indentation ..." warning. I'm not sure what the issue is, as it appears to me that the above is how interfaces generally are implemented in F#. Why does the above not compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I can answer the question myself. I didn't put member in front of the implementation. Exchanging

```
this.Equals other = this.Equals other
```

with

```
member this.Equals other = this.Equals other
```

makes everything alright. The fact that the compiler outlined the "with" keyword as the issue threw me off.

Comment: There have been some work in later versions of F# to improve error reporting. This seems like a good candidate. Perhaps post this as an issue on: github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/issues ?